# Can I execute SonarQube from Gradle custom task?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

Can I execute SonarQube from Gradle custom task?
I would like to set projectKey & Name dynamically as bellows:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://example.com:10009"
        property "sonar.login", "ffabcdfa0e21dcdf039d4dd5d1d999997d930b270a"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"

        // set dynamically
        property "sonar.projectKey",  "$project.ext.sonarqube_projectkey"
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        property "sonar.projectName", "$project.ext.sonarqube_projectname"
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        property "sonar.projectVersion", android.defaultConfig.versionName
        property "sonar.projectBaseDir", "${rootDir}/../"
    }
}

task run_sonarqube_A {
    doFirst {
        project.ext.sonarqube_projectkey = "key_foo_A"
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
        project.ext.sonarqube_projectname= "name_foo_A"
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    doLast {
        // how to execute sonarqube?
    }
}

task run_sonarqube_B {
    doFirst {
        project.ext.sonarqube_projectkey = "key_foo_B"
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
        project.ext.sonarqube_projectname= "name_foo_B"
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    doLast {
        // how to execute sonarqube?
    }
}
```

I tried as belows:

```
sonarqube.shouldRunAfter run_sonarqube_A
```

failed as belows:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\project\99_system\foo\build.gradle' line: 212

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':foo'.
> Could not find method shouldRunAfter() for arguments [task ':foo:run_sonarqube_A'] on object of type org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeExtension.
```

Is there any way to execute SonarQube from custom task?

What I want is executing sonarqube automatically if I run 'gradlew run_sonarqube_A' only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. For me it looks that you just want to execute a SonarQube analysis. It is possible by using [SonarQube Gradle Plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube). How to do it is described on [SonarScanner for Gradle](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/).

You should add:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.8'
}
```

remove all `sonar` properties and `run_sonarqube` task, and next execute:

```
gradle sonarqube -Dsonar.host.url=http://example.com:10009 -Dsonar.login=ffabcdfa0e21dcdf039d4dd5d1d999997d930b270a
```

These properties:

- sonar.sourceEncoding
- sonar.projectKey
- sonar.projectName
- sonar.projectVersion
- sonar.projectBaseDir

are filed by basing on Gradle metadata. For example `sonar.projectKey` is equal to `group` and project `name`

`build.gradle`

```
group = 'org.example'
```

`settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'project'
```

then

```
sonar.projectKey=org.example:project
```

There is no a problem to set `group` or `name` dynamically, because they are defined in Groovy scripts (`build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`).